# Rotate Encryption Keys Azure Data Lake Store

Tags: azure-powershell, azure-data-lake

I have created a PowerShell Script which creates a new version of User Managed Encryption Key in Azure Key Vault and update the Data Lake Store Encryption Key to the new version. Below is the script

```
$subscriptionID = 'XXXX'
$keyVaultName = 'XXXX'
$keyName = 'XXXX'
$adlsName = 'XXXX'

Login-AzureRmAccount
Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId $subscriptionID

$azureKVKey = Add-AzureKeyVaultKey -VaultName $keyVaultName -Name $keyName -Destination Software
$adlsKVVersion = $azureKVKey.Version

Set-AzureRmDataLakeStoreAccount -Name $adlsName -KeyVersion $adlsKVVersion
(Get-AzureRmDataLakeStoreAccount -Name $adlsName).Properties.EncryptionConfig.KeyVaultMetaInfo.EncryptionKeyVersion
```

The script successfully creates a new version of the key but the ADLS encryption key version does not change.

I debugged it and I can also see that the the PS command sends a request for updating the encryption key version

[image: PS Request body]

The response of the PS script still shows the old version of the encryption key
[image: PS Response body]

Any hints as to what might be going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Even though the response shows the old version of the encryption key, the information should be properly updated in the system. To verify this, you could run Get-AdlStoreAccount and see the encryptionKeyVersion.

Could you rerun the command in question and see whether the response shows the correct key version now?

Comment: @Matt I already verified the key version on the portal and sadly it is still pointing to the old version. It has an information section on top which says the a new version is available. Clicking that updates the key to the new version but somehow it is not working from PS :(

Comment: I looked into this, and the encryption key rotation did occur, but the old version is being returned when querying via the API. There will be a fix within the next week that should address the issue, so the API will return the correct version. (The fix will be visible when using PS, the portal, or any of the other interfaces.) Please check back after a week and let me know if you still see this issue.

Comment: Cool. Will check back probably after Christmas :). Thank you Matt

Comment: Great! This should now be resolved.